# OpenGL game runs fine in Win7, drops to 5fps in Windows 8?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, performance, opengl, windows-8

I have just recently installed Windows 8, and I tried to compile and build a simple c++ game project in VS 2010, but when I did, it was running at 5 fps. On windows 7, it runs at a solid 60 fps. Nothing has been changed in the code, but there is just horrible slow down.

I have updated my video drivers, but there is still horrible lag. I thought the problem was to do with compatibility issues with windows 8 and OpenGL, but I can't find anything to confirm this. I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem, and if you have solved it.

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate graphics drivers?

Comment: Try printing the result of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` to make sure you're actually using the video card.

Comment: Additionally, try creating a new OpenGL project and keep adding parts of your game back until you find where the FPS is getting killed.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you test your graphics card / drivers first. All sorts of driver issues could arise when you upgrade operating systems. One of the best tests would be to download Cinebench and see how it performs. Cinebench will evaluate your OpenGL performance. If you get poor results, then you know it's a hardware / driver issue and not an issue with your application.

If the Cinebench results are good, then you can move on to the recommendations made by @Robert Rouhani (comments).

http://www.maxon.net/products/cinebench/overview.html

Comment: Thanks. It seems like my laptop can't even run the test. That isn't a good sign, lol.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of video card do you have in the Win8 machine?

If it's a laptop you might be battling against nVidia Optimus (or an equivalent technology?). Basically programs have to tell the OS in advance that they want to use the video card or they get defaulted to using the low power GPU embedded in the CPU (note: over-simplification).

If this is the case, there's some options in the nVidia control panel to let you create a profile telling the OS to run your app with the discrete GPU, rather than the embedded one.